# Power BI. Using custom map as base map

Tags: powerbi, visualization, topojson

Currently, I am trying to find a way to load a custom map as a base map in Power BI. As I want to be able to load the map even when I have no connection to the internet, I have considered using my company's WMS servers, however that does not seem to be possible in Power BI right now.

Thus, I'm trying to convert this file https://data.gov.sg/dataset/master-plan-2014-planning-area-boundary-web to the TopoJSON format so I am able to use it as a shape map in Power BI.

After using the [Mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/) tool, the file appears fine on Mapshaper: 
[image]

However, in Power BI, it appears like this: 
[image]

Am I doing something wrong or do is there extra steps I need to do? Or is there any other way to load my own custom map in Power BI as a base map?

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to the issues that I faced when trying to create a custom shape map.  The 'picasso-like' rendering of the map was the same.  It turned out to be the projection of the new map was not one of the projections the Power BI likes.  If you can change the projection of your map, it should work.  In mapshaper, load the map, then select console, then enter PROJ WGS84, and it should work. If your starting projection is one that mapshaper doesn't recognize, you have to reproject the original map into something that mapshaper knows.  In my case it didn't recognize the EPSG:3005 projection initially, but when I re-projected in EPSG:4326, then used mapshaper to convert to topojson, I was able to use my custom shape map.